# convert String to double with '%'

Tags: java, number-formatting

I have a String value like "1.22%". I want to convert this to double value.
Douboe.parseDouble throws numberFormatException.

```
String s = "1.22%";
 double iRate;

iRate = Double.parseDouble(s);
```

Comment: You need to use String manipulations like replace(...) to remove the % symbol, then Double.parseDouble() to convert it to double.

Comment: `double` is a number. It *cannot* hold a percent sign.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One-liner using [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html):

```
double d = new DecimalFormat("0.0#%").parse("1.22%").doubleValue(); 
// d = 0.0122
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a method similar to the one below:

```
public static double ConvertPercentageStringToDouble(this string value)
{
   return double.Parse(value.Replace("%","")) / 100;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have standard format. You can try

```
String s = "1.22%";
s = s.replaceAll("%","");
double iRate= Double.parseDouble(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

The better way to do this is using **DecimalFormatSymbols**, which can help you to define what is simbols and what is really numbers to transform into Double.

See the example below:

```
    String s = "1.22%";

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
    DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    symbols.setDecimalSeparator('.');
    symbols.setGroupingSeparator(' ');
    symbols.setPercent('%');
    df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);
    Number parse = df.parse(s);

    Double myDouble = parse.doubleValue();

    System.out.println(myDouble);
```